# Python Least Squares for multiple variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a optimization problem that I need to solve in python. The general structure is

```
def foo(a, b, c, d, e):
    # do something and return one value


def bar(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j):
    # do something and return one value


def func():
    return foo(a, b, c, d, e) - bar(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

I would like to use `least_squares` minimization and return the values for `f, g, h, i and j` as a list where the square difference is the minimum between `foo` and `bar`. I'm not sure how to use `least_squares` for this.

I've tried this:

```
# Initial values f, g, h, i, j
x0 =[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.05,0.5]

# Constraints
lb = [0,0,0,0,-0.9]
ub = [1, 100, 1, 0.5, 0.9]

x = least_squares(func, x0, lb, ub)
```

How do I get `x` to be the returned value of the list of `f, g, h, i and j` minimum values?

Comment: have you tried `least_squares` method provided by `scipy` ? details https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html

Comment: @Anil_M How exactly do you use this function is my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you currently define your problem is equivalent to maximizing `bar` (assuming you pass `func` to a minimization function). As you don't vary the parameters `a` to `e`, `func` basically is the difference between a constant and the outcome of `bar` that can be tuned; due to the negative sign, it will be tried to be maximized as that would then minimize the entire function.

I think what you actually want to minimize is the absolute value or squared difference between the two functions. I illustrate that using a simple example where I assume that the functions just return the sum of the parameters:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def foo(a, b, c, d, e):
    # do something and return one value

    return a + b + c + d + e

def bar(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j):
    # do something and return one value
    return a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j

def func1(x):
    # your definition, the total difference
    return foo(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]) - bar(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9])

def func2(x):
    # quadratic difference
    return (foo(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]) - bar(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9]))**2

# Initial values for all variables
x0 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.5)

# Constraints
# lb = [0,0,0,0,-0.9]
# ub = [1, 100, 1, 0.5, 0.9]
# for illustration, a, b, c, d, e are fixed to 0; that should of course be changed
bnds = ((0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0., 1), (0., 100.), (0, 1), (0, 0.5), (-0.9, 0.9))

res1 = minimize(func1, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)
res2 = minimize(func2, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)
```

Then you get:

```
print res1.x
array([   0. ,    0. ,    0. ,    0. ,    0. ,    1. ,  100. ,    1. ,
          0.5,    0.9])
```

and

```
print res1.fun
-103.4
```

As explained above, all the parameters will go to the upper bound to maximize `bar` which minimizes `func`.

For the adapted function `func2`, you receive:

```
res2.fun
5.7408853312979541e-19  # which is basically 0

res2.x
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.15254237,  0.15254237,  0.15254237,  0.01525424, -0.47288136])
```

So, as expected, for this simple case one can choose the parameters in a way that the difference between these two functions becomes 0. Clearly, the result for your parameters is not unique, they could also be all 0.

I hope that helps to make your actual functions work.

EDIT:

As you asked for `least_square`, that also works fine (use function definition from above); then the total difference is ok:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

lb = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.9]
ub = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,1, 100, 1, 0.5, 0.9]
res_lsq = least_squares(func1, x0, bounds=(lb, ub))
```

Then you receive the same result as above:

```
res_lsq.x
array([  1.00000000e-10,   1.00000000e-10,   1.00000000e-10,
         1.00000000e-10,   1.00000000e-10,   1.52542373e-01,
         1.52542373e-01,   1.52542373e-01,   1.52542373e-02,
        -4.72881356e-01])

res_lsq.fun
array([ -6.88463034e-11])  # basically 0
```

As 5 parameters won't be varied in this problem, I would fix them to a certain value and would not pass them to the optimization call.